# How Can I "Force Close" A Postgres Process

Tags: postgresql

From this Stack Overflow post, [UPDATE statement hangs because of locks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49272719/update-statement-hangs-because-of-locks), I figured out that my DB had gotten locked up because of some sort of bad process.  I used a query:

```
SELECT usename, datname, pid, query_start, state FROM pg_stat_activity;
```

To find the process ID, then tried killing it with `pg_cancel_backend` ... but I got:

```
# SELECT pg_cancel_backend(216700);
ERROR:  canceling statement due to user request
```

and the process wasn't canceled (I could still see it using that query). So, I tried using:

```
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(8838);
```

instead ... and got:

```
# SELECT pg_terminate_backend(216463);
FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
server closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.
The connection to the server was lost. Attempting reset: Succeeded.
```

After all that, the process is back on the list, as if I never tried to remove it (only now it has a new pid):

```
# SELECT usename,datname,pid,query_start,state FROM pg_stat_activity;
 usename  |    datname    |  pid   |         query_start          | state  
----------+---------------+--------+------------------------------+--------
          |               | 216379 |                              | 
 postgres |               | 216381 |                              | 
 admin    | my_project    | 216700 | 2023-11-25 12:53:05.52079-08 | active
          |               | 216377 |                              | 
          |               | 216376 |                              | 
          |               | 216378 |                              | 
(6 rows)
```

However, my application (`my_project`) isn't running, so there is nothing external to PostgreSQL that could be restarting the process.  It seems PosgreSQL is restarting it after my kill attempt?

Is there any third command, beyond `pg_cancel_backend` and `pg_terminate_backend`?  Some sort of `pg_cancel_and_I_mean_it_backend` command?

Comment: 1) What is the UPDATE statement? 2) Did you run the commands as a `superuser`? 3) What does [pg_locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-locks.html) show for the `pid`?

Comment: the commands did what you wated it cliosed the service and started a new one so

Comment: 1) Are you *sure* you don't have a copy of your project running? Maybe a zombie process, or a server? That's the most likely explanation. 2) The process is running as admin. Is your project logging into pg as admin? It probably shouldn't, that's bad security.

Comment: Try `netstat` or similar to find out which other processes connect to your database

Comment: The quoted output sure makes it looks like the process you killed was your own process, the one you used to execute the kill statements.

Comment: The UPDATE is a very simple one, run as a normal user (through the Node `pg` module).  I know the app isn't running because I did `killall node` and it found nothing to kill.  I tried `netstat`, but there is a *lot* of output, and I wasn't sure what to `grep` for in it.  And as for killing my own process, yes that's what I'm trying to do, but it seems to respawn.

Comment: @machineghost I wouldn't trust `killall` to be definitive, the process name isn't always what you think it is. Next time try `ps aux | grep node` or `pgrep node`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up just restarting the machine running PostgreSQL and that fixed whatever zombie process I had.